# How to find a similarity of two words and remove any further similarities from a list in a more efficient way?

Tags: python

I am attempting to create the Just One board game, and I am having a hard time finding an efficient way to remove similar clues without having spaghetti code. The way the game works is that any submitted clues that are similar are removed from the clues list, which is what I am trying to replicate here. From what I can tell, it does seem to work with at least two clues that are the same (example bones, bone, and wishbone). Is there a more effective and less spaghetti-like way to write this?

```
for y in range(0,len(clues)):
if y == len(clues)-1:
    break
for z in range(y+1,len(clues)):
    if clues[y] in clues[z] or clues[z] in clues[y]:
        first_word = str(clues[y])
        second_word = str(clues[z])
        try:
            while True:
                clues.remove(first_word)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            while True:
                clues.remove(second_word)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I would usually turn the data from a list into a set. Sets usually only take 1 of the data, a set can't store the same data, so I think by turning your list into a set with the `set()` functions, it will erase all similar pieces of data.

Code:

```py
clues = [1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3]
print(clues)
clues = set(clues)
print(clues)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3]
{1, 2, 3, 5}
```